# Pandas get average and remove duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(...)
```

---

```
A  B  C
x  3  .
x  5  . 
x  1  .
y  6  .
y  4  .
z  1  .
z  1  .
z  2  .
z  4  .
```

Can someone tell me how can I achieve this:

```
A  B
x  3
y  5
z  2
```

**1.** Drop column C
**2.** Calculate the average based on column A
**3.** Remove duplicate rows based on column A

It's my first adventure with python, sorry for spam - I tried to use others answers but nothing is working for me.

Comment: What have you tried? You can drop in quick search terms like "drop column pandas" or "pandas group by and average" etc. on google, you'll find a lot of resources including the official docs.

Comment: I tried that:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919570/pandas-calculating-the-mean-values-of-duplicate-entries-in-a-dataframe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ali":["x","x","x","y","y","z",'z'],"mali":[1,10,2,4,6,6,7]})

#output
    ali mali
0   x   1
1   x   10
2   x   2
3   y   4
4   y   6
5   z   6
6   z   7


df.groupby("ali")["mali"].mean()

ali
x    4.333333
y    5.000000
z    6.500000
Name: mali, dtype: float64
```

for your code that would be

```
df.groupby("A")["B"].mean()
```

Comment: it means your columns that you are trying to use is not int or float.
to solve it 
`df["column"] = df["column"].to_numeric()` then apply the aggregation that i send u

Comment: It makes sense but I can't use that method `to_numeric()`. `!df1.groupby('code')["range"].to_numeric().mean()
*** AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'`

Comment: re read what ii told u to do ... i said make the column numeric before u do any regrouping

Comment: Ahhh okay I finally did it. Sorry man I am so tired because of this ugly thing. Too much python for me :D Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import requests
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AlbertKozera/6396b4333d1a9222193e11401069ed9a/raw/ab8733a2135bcf61999bbcac4f92e0de5fd56794/Pojazdy%2520elektryczne%2520w%2520USA.csv'
r = requests.get(url)

from io import StringIO
with StringIO(r.text) as sio:
    df = pd.read_csv(sio)


print(df.head(3))

x =df.drop(['state', 'brand', 'model', 'year of production', 'type'], axis=1)
df2 = df.groupby('code').range.mean()

print("\n GROUPBY State x Range (mean)")
print(df2.head())
```

Comment: suggest renaming 'range' to something else... reserved for python